# Bookmarklet to select all friends and add them to an event on Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to make a bookmarklet to allow me to select all my friends in the dialog to create an event on Facebook. Examining the source with Firebug shows the following:

The div container for each person gets a new class label of

```
selectedCheckable
```

when it it is clicked, So I have written this like of JS to try and select all the div's and give them this class:

```
$(".checkableListItem").addClass("selectedCheckable");
```

This works in selecting them, however when it comes time to press the "Save and close" button, the changes do not seem to have any effect in selecting all the friends to add to the event. It seems that FB has a different way of marking the friends that have been selected to add to the event. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction so I can accomplish this? Thanks in advance, RayQuang :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I advise instead of making your own couldn't you just use one of these Greasmonkey scripts?

http://userscripts.org/scripts/search?q=facebook+invite&submit=

That's what I was doing and it was working for my events. Let me know if it works for you.